# PHP Chat client using XMPP - Fatal error Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, timeout, xmpp, chat, openfire

I installed an Openfire server, and created 2 users to chat with each other using the XMPP protocol.

I took a sample PHP project from here: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/PHP/Q_26533833.html

This is the code snippet:

```
<?php

// activate full error reporting
//error_reporting(E_ALL & E_STRICT);

include 'XMPPHP/XMPP.php';

#Use XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_VERBOSE to get more logging for error reports
#If this doesn't work, are you running 64-bit PHP with < 5.2.6?

$conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP('pc27', 5222, 'user1', 'user1', 'xmpphp', 'pc27', $printlog=true, $loglevel=XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_INFO);
try {
$conn->connect();
$conn->processUntil('session_start');
$conn->presence();
$conn->message('user2@pc27', 'This is a test message!');
$conn->disconnect();
} catch(XMPPHP_Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

But when I hit the url: localhost/Chat/sendmessage_example.php, I get the following message on the screen:

```
1403610021 [INFO]: Connecting to tcp://pc27:5222 Connecting to tcp://pc27:5222 user1@pc27 1403610021 [INFO]: Starting TLS encryption 
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in D:\xampp\htdocs\Chat\XMPPHP\XMPP.php on line 392

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\xampp\htdocs\Chat\XMPPHP\XMLStream.php on line 475
```

**What I tried**: ini_set("max_execution_time", 300); does not work (the same error recurs).

Also, I don't understand why does it connect to "tcp://pc27:5222" ? Shouldn't "tcp" be "localhost" or the local ip ? Is this the cause of the timeout error ?

Comment: What I've done so far:

1) Added the line after connect() and processUntil(): $conn->presence($status='Controller available.');

2) Uncommented the line in php.ini under xampp/php: extension=php_openssl.dll

3) Added the path to libeay32.dll under PATH variable.

Running a sample PHPINFO page also shows that OpenSSL is enabled.

Now, when I try to connect, I get the following:
**Connecting to tcp://pc27:5222 user1@pc27**

Answer (score 0):

Its working now. These are the steps that I followed:

**1)** Changed depcrecated use of "split" to "explode" in XMPPHP/XMLStream.php and XMPPHP/XMPP.php files.

**2)** Added timeout to 300 secs in the Php example like this: ini_set("max_execution_time", 300);

**3)** Added the line after ->connect() and ->processUntil(): $conn->presence($status='Controller available.');

**4)** Uncommented this line in xampp/php/php.ini: extension=php_openssl.dll

**5)** Added the path to libeay32.dll under PATH variable of Environment variables.

Comment: could you please say in detail about number 5. i am using php 5.4.161. every thing about 1 to 4 was correct by default.

Comment: Hi Ehsan. I logged in to my Stackoverflow account after a long time. This question was asked 2 years ago, and I've also changed roles and companies and technologies. I've a very faint memory of this. Environment variables are those that you set for JDK and PHP. So, no.5 seems to be similar.